# Save an std::map<int, std::vector<int>> in Oracle12c

Tags: c++, arrays, oracle, occi

How do I store an array of numbers in an Oracle column?

I have an std::map> mymap and I want to store all data in the mymap in the table.

The table should have two columns

1. an id, the key of the mymap
2. and this is what I am looking here

What data type is needed to store the std::vector which represents the value of my key?

How it is done in Oracle12c?

Comment: What have you tried? What code do you have so far? What's your *specific* problem?

Comment: I am using OCCI and it works well until now. I just want the proper type way to save an std::vector in a column.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am OK with the comma separated value. What data type do I need?

Comment: The usual way is to store a row with key,value for every entry in the vector.

Comment: I don't want to create 10K tables in the database. The std::map might contain a lot of IDs

Comment: 10K is to low to measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize the vector to a comma separated list of numbers (or some other format) and store that, then deserialize when reading. Just one of many options. Another would be to store the individual numbers in some other table with a key indicating they are the same "vector". It could be solved in *many* ways.

Comment: No, I don't want to use a separate table. I want a table that needs to store the participation event (ID) and the list of participants. So in one table I need all the information.

Comment: I'm confused. You voted to close yet still posted an answer.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious yes I did. I voted to close since I think it's a poor question, but I still answered it the best I could, because; why not? The answer might still help OP.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the question is edited.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You should not be answering something that should be closed.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270418/answering-a-question-which-you-vote-to-close-as-off-topic

Comment: @NathanOliver perhaps not, but in this case I did.